# Trim white spaces in Flask-wtforms

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have some string fields that I would like to prevent from having any white spaces. How is this done in Flask-wtforms?

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    first_name = StringField('First name',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=64)])
    last_name = StringField('Last name',validators=[DataRequired(),Length(min=2,max=64)])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Regexp:

```
validators.Regexp('^\w+$', message="Username must contain only letters numbers or underscore"),
```

http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#wtforms.validators.Regexp